# How to overgive a object function right in php?

Tags: php, oop

I have a PHP project where I build a kind of DOM with PHP objects. Starts with a parent class 'fs' witch holds every object of the webpage in a structure.
I want that objects can send each other messages through the parent object 'system'. 'system'-object holds the references for core objects (config, database, template, users, ...). I build a method, with should organize the communication of the 'subobjects' where the name of the object and the called method are permitted by parameters.

Looks like... (debug messages should be ignored...)

```
public static function doWith( $object, $function, $vars = "" ) {
            $object = strtoupper($object);
            if( is_object($this->$object) ) {
                $this->$object->$function ($vars);
            } else {
                print("empty!");
            }
        }
```

But still this, the code doesn't want to do. Where is my problem? Can't methods be called via $this->$var->$method () ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: the syntax is `$this->var->object`, no additional dollar signs after `$this`

Comment: saved the objects in the 'system'-object into instances. Want to call them through overgiven parameters. So I want this command to be dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` does not exist in a static function.
If the data you are trying to access is from a static variable/function, you can use `self` to reach it:

```
self::$object
```

If the `$object` is not a static member, you will either have to make it static, or create a instance of the `class` before using it.